# SwipeRefreshLayout + another view

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I have my layout setup as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include layout="@layout/my_toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.my.SubView
            android:id="@+id/my_list_subview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:maxLines="3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the SwipeRefreshLayout takes up the entire screen and the textview doesn't show up at all.

[image: Blue line is where the textview is]

The blue line in the above image is where the text view is. Is there anything I am missing? This seems to be so simple a problem, its ludicrous!

Image 2 in response to the answer by @Tomar[image]

Comment: Try building the layout from bottom to top using a RelativeLayout using layout_above.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. In either case somehow, the swipe refresh layout wants to take up the entire space till the bottom. If I move the textview up, it shows up properly, but not below.

Comment: Do one thing take the parent layout height as match_parent.

Comment: And it may be just on the preview, try running the app?

Comment: Tried adjusting height as well. (the edit and the answer below).

Comment: Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303795/adjust-swiperefreshlayout-height-to-place-view-at-the-bottom-of-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/my_toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/text_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.my.SubView
            android:id="@+id/my_list_subview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:maxLines="3"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It shows up as in figure 2 (added to the main question as I cannot add it in the comment).

Comment: @GreenBee try now

Comment: Thanks. Adding `android:layout_below="@+id/top_layout"` works! I dislike RelativeLayouts, but apparently I cannot get it to work with Linear! I actually got it working with ConstraintLayout with a _kind of_ kludge.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned above, I worked it out with ConstraintLayout as below. I do not know why I need to use a large bottom margin and padding in the swipe refresh layout for it to sit above the text. Without these, it doesn't work!

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_super_large"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
        <com.my.SubView
            android:id="@+id/my_list_subview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="@string/write_message"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_large"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
           android:id="@+id/srl_reload_list"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_openOrderList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```