# Expandable Edittext in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline

Gosh, simple things are so hidden and tedious in Android! I have an edittext box that starts as a single line but takes multiline input. When the text is filled up, the edit box expands but only to overlap with the views above it! I want the views above it pushed up automatically, not overlapped. How do I achieve this simple thing?

FWIW, the layout is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787257/swiperefreshlayout-another-view) (ConstraintLayout).

An example of the expandable edittext that I am looking for is the one used in Google Hangouts or WhatsApp for entering text.

Edit: Using `RelativeLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout` works. The edittext box auto-expands pushing other views up. I officially declare my love for `RelativeLayout` whatever its pitfalls are!

If someone has a solution for CL instead, please let me know.

Edit 2: The `RelativeLayout` solution only works if there is a `SwipeRefreshLayout` contained within. It doesn't work with plain old `RecyclerView`.

Comment: would it help to put `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/swipe_refresh"` on toolbar so it gets chained as well and gets pushed up?

Comment: @wick.ed, no that didn't help. The thing is, the swiperefreshlayout is overlapped by the edittext box.